# how to print out the right answers in a list

Tags: python

I wanna put all the right answers in a list and make a condition about the answers if the user will repeat their answers, they will not get a point once it is in the list. I got a problem where only the first input will detect right and the rest of the condition will not meet.

```
while again: 
    for i in range(0,10):
        answer = []
        answerlst = input(str(i + 1) + '. ').upper()
    
        if f'{answerlst}\n' in f.read():
            print ("found")
            answer.append(answerlst)
        else:
            print("not found")
        print(answer)
            ask = input("Wanna play again? [Y] / [N]: ").upper()       
        if ask == 'Y':
            again = True
        else:
            again = False
```

For example, I inputted spider, at first, it will detect as found, in the 2nd input, if I inputted height, it will detect as not found when it should meet the first condition. Plus, from the else condition, if the user inputted a wrong answer, the loop won't exit and it just go back from inputting answers where the program should be exited. I am pretty sure I got a problem from the looping but I cannot figured out how.

topic1. txt

SPIDER

HEIGHT

Comment: it is actually i think it is the end of the file i guess, it does not give the same result as there is no new line after the last line/word

Comment: Yes, there is no new line in the text file. How can I make the user input to detect if the word he has been inputted is in the file? I tried without the f'{answerlst}\n but what happening is, for example I only inputted 'S', in my text file, the word is SPIDER, but it will detect as found. @GhostOps

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regex

```py
import re

while again: 
    for i in range(0,10):
        answer = []
        answerlst = input(str(i + 1) + '. ').upper()
    
        if re.search(f'{answer}(?:$|\r?\n)', f.read()):
            print("found")
            answer.append(answerlst)
        else:
            print("not found")
        print(answer)
            ask = input("Wanna play again? [Y] / [N]: ").upper()       
        if ask == 'Y':
            again = True
        else:
            again = False
```

It actually checks that whether your word is in any line in the file

Or you can also try `f.readlines()`

```py
while again: 
    for i in range(0,10):
        answer = []
        answerlst = input(str(i + 1) + '. ').upper()
    
        if answer in f.readlines():
            print("found")
            answer.append(answerlst)
        else:
            print("not found")
        print(answer)
            ask = input("Wanna play again? [Y] / [N]: ").upper()       
        if ask == 'Y':
            again = True
        else:
            again = False
```

Tell me if its not working for you...

Comment: I am receving an error: unterminated character set at position 0

Comment: can u post the full traceback? it's working for me tho...

Comment: Message=unterminated character set at position 1
  Source=D:\VB\Test\Test\Test.py
  StackTrace:
  File "D:\VB\Test\Test\Test.py", line 10, in <module> (Current frame)
    if re.search(f'^{answer}$', f.read()):

Comment: i changed the code try again

Comment: Message=unterminated character set at position 0 (line 1, column 1)
  Source=D:\VB\Test\Test\Test.py
  StackTrace:
  File "D:\VB\Test\Test\Test.py", line 9, in <module> (Current frame)
    if re.search(f'{answer}(?:$|\r?\n)', f.read()):
This is the error in your new code.

Comment: but i got no errors tho, is that the full traceback?

Comment: Yes. That's the full traceback. What I did to your code is that, I added again = True at the top because of the while loop and open the text file for the condition and just fix the indentation in part of "ask"

Comment: but when i ran the `re.search(f'{answer}(?:$|\r?\n)', f.read())` line alone, i got no errors and it works fine for me, try running this line alone and tell if there's still any errors

Comment: `import re

answer = []

f = open('D:/VB/PRELIM/topic1.txt')
for i in range(0,10):
    answerlst = input(str(i + 1) + '. ').upper()
    
    if re.search(f'{answer}(?:$|\r?\n)', f.read()):
        print("found")
        answer.append(answerlst)
    else:
        print("not found")
    print(answer)`

This is the code. Tell me what I did wrong

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how can I make spaces between the code.

Comment: then try normal string concatenation `answer + '(?:$|\\r?\\n)'` instead of `f'{answer}(?:$|\r?\n)'`

Comment: I still have the same error. On the other hand, 

I figured out the answer. ` text = f.read().strip().split()` . I just add this below the opening of the file and for the condition, ` if answerlst in text:` This working.

Comment: @Jay i added another code in my answer, check it out

Comment: I tried the code, I don't have an error but there is a bug where the input cannot be added on the list and it does not meet the first condition. Whatever I inputted, it says "not found"

Comment: well f.readlines() is nothing but splits the text file's content by newline, thats why i added it to my answer though